# Swift 3.0.2 and Realm - Compile Errors

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am bumping into an issue while trying to use Realm in a Swift 3.0.2 iOS project. Starting simple, I would like to apply it to a class named `Genre`:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Genre: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int
    dynamic var name: String

    init?(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }

}
```

Looks quite simple, right? Despite this, I am getting the following compile error:

```
Genre.swift:23:1: 'required' initializer 'init()' must be provided by subclass of 'Object'

Genre.swift:23:1: 'required' initializer 'init(realm:schema:)' must be provided by subclass of 'Object'

Genre.swift:23:1: 'required' initializer 'init(value:schema:)' must be provided by subclass of 'Object'
```

Any got a hint on how I could solve this? From what I have seen online, it shouldn't be necessary for me to implement those methods.

Setup:

- Xcode 8.2.1
- Swift 3.0.2
- Realm installed using Cocoapod

Comment: when do you get this error?

Comment: @GaneshKumar As mentioned in the question when I compile (or Run, if you prefer) the project.

Answer (score 2):

[Overriding `init` directly isn't possible in Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1849).

You can get around this by marking your `init` as a `convenience` one.

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Genre: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int
    dynamic var name: String

    convenience init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.init()            
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```